# GRANT specific role ALTER access to specific table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have tried many ways to do this with no success, but what I want to do is the following:

```
GRANT ALTER ON [dbo].[theTable] TO [role]
```

Bonus if you can also provide me some permission state before & after eg.

```
SELECT * 
FROM fn_my_permissions('dbo.theTable', 'TABLE');
```

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why do you believe it is not successful?  Are you receiving an error message?  fn_my_permissions does not accept 'TABLE' as a 2nd parameter.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176097.aspx

Comment: Because I know it's not successful as it doesn't let me do it even though I am dbo. I know 'TABLE' doesn't work, but 'DATABASE' doesn't return any of my roles.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`GRANT ALTER ON object TO principal` is the correct form of the statement in your case.

To view the permissions granted to you on the object, use the [`fn_my_permissions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176097.aspx) function like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.fn_my_permissions('object', 'OBJECT')
;
```

Answer (score 15):

```
GRANT ALTER ON [dbo].[theTable] TO [role] 
GO
```

Comment: This fixed the problem. Thanks a lot.