# FluentMigrator - how to alter table permissions?

Tags: fluent-migrator, database-versioning, migratordotnet

I have started using FluentMigrator as my database migration tool for my MSSQL databases. It seems to cater for most of my needs in regards to CRUD table operations and seeding.

However i simply cannot find a way to configure table permissions after i have created a table.

I know i could simply run a .sql with the GRANT PUBLIC SELECT ON BLAH statement but i would really like to use the fluent api instead.

Do you know a way to alter permissions using the fluent api?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GRANT specific role ALTER access to specific table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9222569/grant-specific-role-alter-access-to-specific-table)

Answer (score 0):

It's not available in the fluent api, you will have to Execute a script in the migration via the Execute function.